# Meaning of xserversock and xclientsock in ssh2 library for x11 forwarding

Tags: node.js, networking, ssh, x11, x11-forwarding

I'm trying to understand how x11 port forwarding inside SSH connections works programmatically.

In particular, I'm trying to understand this part of the README that is part of the code recipes inside [Node's SSH2 client library](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2). Once the client is instantiated, what do the variables `xserversock` and `xclientsock` do? Why does `xclientsock` pipe data back to itself through `xserversock`? Finally, does `xserversock` actually connect to `127.0.0.1:6000`, or to `10.13.23.10:6000`?

```
var net = require('net');

var Client = require('ssh2').Client;

var conn = new Client();

conn.on('x11', function(info, accept, reject) {
  var xserversock = new net.Socket();
  xserversock.on('connect', function() {
    var xclientsock = accept();
    xclientsock.pipe(xserversock).pipe(xclientsock);
  });
  // connects to localhost:0.0
  xserversock.connect(6000, 'localhost');
});

conn.on('ready', function() {
  conn.exec('xeyes', { x11: true }, function(err, stream) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var code = 0;
    stream.on('end', function() {
      if (code !== 0)
        console.log('Do you have X11 forwarding enabled on your SSH server?');
      conn.end();
    }).on('exit', function(exitcode) {
      code = exitcode;
    });
  });
}).connect({
  host: '10.13.23.10',
  username: 'foo',
  password: 'bar'
});
```

Answer (score 2):

1. `xserversock` is the connection to the X server running locally on your machine. `xclientsock` is the stream representing the incoming X client request (e.g. xeyes in the example) to your local X server.
2. `xclientsock.pipe(xserversock).pipe(xclientsock);` is not `xclientsock` piping to itself, it is merely allowing data to flow in both directions between the local X server and the remote X client. `pipe()` always returns the stream passed to it, to allow for easy chaining of streams. So this one line of code is equivalent to:

   ```
   xclientsock.pipe(xserversock);
   xserversock.pipe(xclientsock);
   ```
3. Finally, remember `xserversock` is a socket that is connecting to your *local* X server. This is evident with the `.connect()` arguments passed to the socket, so it will be connecting to 127.0.0.1:6000.